# Draw NSImage (with NSBezierPath) on top of NSOpenGLView

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl

I have `NSImage`, and I draw `NSBezierPath` to it. After that I need to draw that NSImage on top of `NSOpenGLView` to achieve result like that:

[image]

Is it possible, and how can I do it? `NSImage` is ready, it only needs to be drawn on top of NSOpenGLView.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:your_frame_here]
[imageView setImage:image]; //Your Image
[openGLView addSubView:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help, I have the same problem using opengl. The solution for me was to change the surface order parameter of the context of the openglView

```
GLint order = -1; // below window   
[context setValues:&order forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOrder];
```

this will allow your top view to be drawn after opengl flushBuffer command;

this is the documentation form apple where i found this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/opengl-macprogguide/opengl_contexts/opengl_contexts.html